# Is "much too many" grammatical?

Tags: adjectives

Can I use "much" to modify and emphasize "too many" or would I have to resort to different adverbs such as "way" or "far"?

> He bought much too many/way too many/far too many apples.

**"Much too many"** certainly sounds bad to me but that doesn't necessarily mean that its wrong and it might just be that there are better options.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a native person and I can only answer this question based on my Grammar book.

[Here](https://books.google.de/books?id=NY8oAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA234&dq=Advanced%20grammar%20in%20use%20Unit%2050&hl=de&pg=PA100#v=onepage&q=Advanced%20grammar%20in%20use%20Unit%2050&f=false), authors explain that

> " we use far (not much or many) before **too+many + a plural countable noun** or **too much + an + uncountable noun**"

I wish it helps.